# Does python automatically delete object?

Tags: python

I have a class like:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.client1   = ThirdPartyLib1.Client(data['a'])
        self.client2   = ThirdPartyLib2.Client(data['b'])
        self.client3   = MyClass2.Client(data['c'])

    def handle(self):
        #self.client1.xxx()
        #....
```

And main code:

```
    while not STOP:
        data = SomeLib.get()

        client = MyClass(data)
        client.handle()
```

So my question is does client automatically be deleted? Is there memory leak?

Do I need to create `__del__` in MyClass and call

```
del self.client1
del self.client2
del self.client3
```

?

Or do I need to add `del client` after `client.handle()` ?

Comment: No, there is no memory leak, Python is a memory managed langauge. `__del__` is not directly related to `del x`, all `del x` does is remove a *name from a local namespace*. If an object is still referenced somewhere else, it will still be alive. CPython uses reference counting, so when an objects reference count reaches 0, it is reclaimed immediately, but that is an implementation detail

Comment: You don't have to explicitly call `del client` to remove it from memory or the stack. When the program or execution code stops running the specific `client` instance, the `handle()` and any other data being passed to `MyClass` is removed from the stack.

Comment: @FishingCode what stack are you talking about precisely?

Comment: @erip yeah, in CPython specifically, when a reference count reaches 0 an object is *immediately* reclaimed, so it can look like that's what it's doing, but in, say, Jython, it is up to the JVM garbage collector.

Comment: This is in reference to the **heap**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you bring a good point, in your first comment, but to your second sentence, `if the object is still referenced somewhere else, it will still be alive` that is true, if you are referring to a different instance (method) call of `MyClass`or do you mean the same instance of the function `client()`, I am thinking that that specific variable is still dead once it's OOS. Once it leaves the scope, that memory is freed up. I may not be 100 % correct.

Comment: I'm saying that objects are not reclaimed until their reference count reaches 0. Scope is only incidentally related to that, in that when local scopes terminate then the local namespace is destroyed and reference counts go down. That may or may not result in objects being reclaimed. I don't know what you mean about the specific variable, variables are not objects, they are names which refer to objects in particular namespaces

Comment: Anyway, the answer to this question is "no, you dont need to `del client`"